# how to check whether NAN is present in json string or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

suppose i have below function, which is getting jsonData in the form of jason, i validate the var jsonData to check for NaN ?

```
function save() {
        var jsonData = getEnteredValue(); 
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : 'saveSalesForecast.json',
            data : 'jsonPostData=' + jsonData,
            success : function() { //alert("success");
            }
        });
    }
```

i only know how to replace NAN but don know how to check for NAN!

```
jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonData.replace(/\bNaN\b/g, "null"));
```

here is remaining function:(any field values can be string,numbers but it should not be NAN

```
  function getEnteredValue() {
    var rowIds = $("#salesForecastGrid").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
    var ids=[];
    var jsonPostData = "[";

    for ( var i = 0; i <= rowIds.length-1; i++) {
    $("#salesForecastGrid").jqGrid('editCell', i, 2, false);
        var forecastedSales = parseFloat($("#salesForecastGrid")
                .jqGrid('getCell', rowIds[i], 'forecastedSales'));

        if (!((forecastedSales == "") || isNaN(forecastedSales) || (forecastedSales ==0))) {
            if (ids.indexOf(rowIds[i])==-1){
                ids.push(rowIds[i]);
                }
            }
    }



    for ( var i = 0; i <= ids.length-1; i++) {
        var forecastedSales = parseFloat($("#salesForecastGrid")
                .jqGrid('getCell', ids[i], 'forecastedSales'));
        var id = $("#salesForecastGrid").jqGrid('getCell', ids[i],
                'id');
        var date = $("#salesForecastGrid").jqGrid('getCell',
                ids[i], 'day');
        if (id < 0) {
            id = 0;
        }

        var record = "{" + "id:" + id + "," + "date:" + date + ","
                + "forecastedSales:" + forecastedSales + "}";
        jsonPostData = jsonPostData + record;
        if (i != ids.length) {
            jsonPostData = jsonPostData + ",";
        }
    }
    jsonPostData += "]";
    return jsonPostData;
}
```

Json Data like:

```
"[{id:68447,date:04-17-2014,forecastedSales:8420.42},{id:68448,date:04-18-2014,‌​forecastedSales:9912.68},]"
```

Comment: why not [isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)?

Comment: @Praveen it could be helpful, if you answer for this using your comment & write few description on it

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for the info.. I was not aware that `JSON.stringify({a: NaN});` results in `'{"a":null}'`.

Comment: @Praveen: Deleted my comment after I saw that the OP is building the JSON **manually**!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are creating the JSON manually, and thus end up with invalid JSON. Do yourself a favor and use [**`JSON.stringify`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
function getEnteredValue() {
    var rowIds = $("#salesForecastGrid").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
    var ids=[];
    var data = [];

    // ...


    for ( var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        // ...

        data.push(
           {id: id, date: date, forecastedSales: forecastedSales}
        );
    }
    return JSON.stringify(data);
}
```

Since `NaN` is not a valid value in JSON, it will automatically be converted to `null`. Example:

```
> JSON.stringify({a: NaN});
  "{"a":null}"
```

---

For more info see [Using native JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_native_JSON).

Comment: +1 efficient approach.  This will help to avoid all sort of error, thanks.

Comment: so, just you have added `return JSON.stringify(data);` to my above function, right?

Comment: Well, you also have to change the function as I showed in my answer. I.e. use an array and add objects to the array (instead of building a string).

Answer (score 0):

`NaN` is not acceptable in JSON. JSON specification does not support `NaN` as a value. Even when javascript object has `NaN` value, it will be converted to `null` when you serialise to JSON format.

First of all, JSON is not an Javascript Object. JSON is general format which can be understand by all languages.